# python code to remove special character '-' from certain strings only

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I'd like to clean the trails of '--' in between column headers and the column data. so that i need to create a dataframe table out of it.

Please find the data below -

```
IP TRACER ID        ID              cId      No    Loop  Element Name                    Freq  STATUS         Severity  Error         Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Source
--------------------  --------------------  -------------  ----  ----  ------------------------------  ----  -------------  --------------  ---------------  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------
2323Z-IH0SLX       20212800032                                                             1     Denied         Error           IEHP_DOSOlderTh  Date is older than 12-months 

2325611-2SU       202210201377                 0           837/002A1/2300/HI/01/02  1     R       valid         0x08C8F       Value of element is incorrect.            
-------------------- ----------------     ---- -------------- --------------------------------------- --------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         
232561-EZBCD       2022112800195                 0           837/00522A1/2300/HI/01/02  1     R       valid         0xC8F       Value of element is incorrect.
```

ive tried to use the command - `data.replace("--", "")`, but since there are '-' in the column data too , its been removed too!

I want the output to be like below.

```
IP TRACER ID        ID              cId      No    Loop  Element Name                    Freq  STATUS         Severity  Error         Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Source

2323Z-IH0SLX       20212800032                                                             1     Denied         Error           IEHP_DOSOlderTh  Date is older than 12-months 
                                                                    IEHP           
2325611-2SU       202210201377                 0           837/002A1/2300/HI/01/02  1     R       valid         0x08C8F       Value of element is incorrect.            
        
232561-EZBCD       2022112800195                 0           837/00522A1/2300/HI/01/02  1     R       valid         0xC8F       Value of element is incorrect.
```

**Note - Removing the second row and last but one row might not be the solution, because data might not be consistent. Even if second row could be, but,  last but one couldnt by using row number.**

Please guide me!

Comment: Can you give a test case, in code, for what you *do* want, and what you *don't*?

Comment: @tadman - added to the post!

Comment: Why not just remove the second line in the file entirely or replace it with a line break? That seems to be what you're after, and would be much easier than trying to apply string manipulation to the entire file.

Comment: Doesn't see any python code, what you have tried? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @esqew - I have updated the post. please check. Removing the second row and last but one row might not be the solution, because data might not be consistent. Even if second row could be, but,  last but one couldnt by using row number.

Comment: @Hermann12 - i have used data.replace("--", "") command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex to check if the line only contains   and `-` seems to work.
We can use `.join` and `.split` to replace lines that march this criteria with empty lines.

```py
data = r'''IP TRACER ID        ID              cId      No    Loop  Element Name                    Freq  STATUS         Severity  Error         Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Source
--------------------  --------------------  -------------  ----  ----  ------------------------------  ----  -------------  --------------  ---------------  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------
2323Z-IH0SLX       20212800032                                                             1     Denied         Error           IEHP_DOSOlderTh  Date is older than 12-months 

2325611-2SU       202210201377                 0           837/002A1/2300/HI/01/02  1     R       valid         0x08C8F       Value of element is incorrect.            
-------------------- ----------------     ---- -------------- --------------------------------------- --------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         
232561-EZBCD       2022112800195                 0           837/00522A1/2300/HI/01/02  1     R       valid         0xC8F       Value of element is incorrect. '''
import re
processed_data = "\n".join("" if re.fullmatch("[ -]+", line) else line for line in data.split("\n"))
print(processed_data)
```

results in

```
IP TRACER ID        ID              cId      No    Loop  Element Name                    Freq  STATUS         Severity  Error         Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Source

2323Z-IH0SLX       20212800032                                                             1     Denied         Error           IEHP_DOSOlderTh  Date is older than 12-months 

2325611-2SU       202210201377                 0           837/002A1/2300/HI/01/02  1     R       valid         0x08C8F       Value of element is incorrect.            

232561-EZBCD       2022112800195                 0           837/00522A1/2300/HI/01/02  1     R       valid         0xC8F       Value of element is incorrect.
```

Comment: Could you please look into it, I'd really appreciate it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77695572/python-code-to-convert-a-bad-txt-file-to-csv-file